# Adding new options / editing the op

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer

I was tasked with writing an add in for the default pages you make in SharePoint Online on the Office 365 page - the ones under "pagename.sharepoint.com/sites/...". I went over WeebHooks, Sharepoint web add-ins (apps), solutions, workflows, but nothing seems to fit the requirements and I'm pretty much lost now.

What I need to know is what kind of add-ins or workflows or whatnot I should write to access the drop-down menus from "pagename.sharepoint.com/sites/pagename/Shared Documents", add new options and connect to Azure's SQL database.

In case my explanation isn't clear enough, this is the site I'm talking about - 
[image: this thing]

Workflows seem unable to add new options to the drop-down menus or add new files, add-ins seem to only be able to create new pages, webhooks seem to be a completely different thing from what I'm looking for. Any directions would be much appreciated. I spent about a week researching and I still have no clue where to start.

Comment: "Editing / Adding new options to Office 365 Sharepoint online page" is what the title was supposed to be, sorry.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.